# send output of batch file to current directory

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

I have a `.bat` script that concats some text files into one big file. I would like to have the resulting file go to the current directory instead of the hardcoded path.

Here is my script:

```
@echo off
:loop
if ($1) == () goto end
more +9 %1% >> %cd%\bigfile.txt
shift
goto loop
:end
```

I have this saved in the "Send To" folder, so I can select a bunch of files in DirectoryA, and right-click and "send to" my batch script. This works, but I want bigfile.txt to be in the same directory as all the little files. Ideas?

Comment: Use %~dp0 instead of %cd% and see if it works. Btw use it like this: %~dp0bigfile.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:loop
    if "%~1"=="" goto :eof
    more +9 "%~1" >> "%~dp1bigfile.txt"

    shift
    goto loop
```

Append the output to a file (`bigfile.txt`) in the same drive and path as the source file

Comment: Hm, this only works for less than about 20 files at a time. If I try to do more, it says `Windows cannot access the specified device, file, or path...` Is there some limit on the number of input arguments?

Comment: @hoosierEE, yes, there is a limit. The command line in windows is limited to 2048 characters in XP and 8192 characters from Vista and later. And the full list of files you select (with its paths) is passed as argument to the batch file in one command line.

Comment: Ah well that is a problem. I ended up using a `for` loop in the end to avoid passing in all the filenames as arguments, but the `%~dp1` still came in handy.

Answer (score 0):

that can be achieved by replacing

```
%cd%\bigfile.txt
```

with

```
%cd:~0,2%%~p1
```

it obtains the string to the path up to the parent directory (with drive specified)